# Using "Outlook:// Protocol", Open Current Instance of Outlook, not New Instance

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html, microsoft-office-2013

### Background

I'm building an Excel webapp using the Javascript API for Office, and in the webapp I have links to MS Outlook using the [Outlook Protocol](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/using-outlook-links/). Example link:

```
<a title="outlook:Inbox/Projects/Current/ExampleProject" href="outlook:Inbox/Projects/Current/ExampleProject" target="_blank">ExampleProject</a>
```

I am running Outlook 2013, in which the protocol has officially been depreciated. It still works when one adds a registry key, though:

[image]

This opens a new instance of Outlook 2013 when the link is clicked on.

### Question

What I'd like it to do is to being the currently running instance up and change the view to the correct folder, instead of always starting a new instance. Is that possible?

---

### Edit

G-Man was able to solve the multiple instance problem by suggesting `/recycle` in the Registry key. Now the only issue I have is that when I click the link it opens an instance of IE11 before changing the Outlook view, and that IE instance doesn't close afterwards.

### Edit 2

To bypass the extra IE instance, I just needed to remove the `target="_blank"`. And we have success!

Comment: Have you tried looking at additional command-line options for Outlook (to use in the command in the Registry string), such as `/recycle`?

Comment: I haven't. The command line is an area in which I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: That's it! I placed `/recycle` in front of `/select` and it works! Brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the Outlook command in the Registry string to include `/recycle` (before `/select`). 
Microsoft’s [Command-line switches for Outlook 2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-2013-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6) page defines `/recycle` as signifying “Starts Outlook by using an existing Outlook window, if one exists.”

Comment: You beat me to it! One note however, if using the Office 365 version of Office 2013, note that Office is installed in a different location by default so you need to alter your registry entry to match.

Comment: Yes im not sure how exactly im going to handle that part. I might write up a javascript which output the correct regedit file when given the user's installation location